# possible to limit retry for a failed message in spring rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

When there is some except throw out to the listener, the message will be re-deliver next time and this is good for us, but is it possible to set a limit for the retries? such as I want to retry 3 times, and  drop the message after retried 3 times.

Comment: Do you use spring-integration?

Comment: yes, I am using rabbit:listener-container

Comment: There is some functionality available in Spring AMQP relating to retries: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#template-retry

Comment: Additionally, you could just take advantage of a chain of RabbitMQ dead letter queues. i.e. Your main queue has a DLQ, which in turn has a DLQ, and so on for as many DLQ/retries as you like. You listen to the DLQs and then anything in a final DLQ causes alerts for manual intervention.

Comment: Have you already seen [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21393517/3364187)?

Answer (score 0):

spring:
rabbitmq:
listener:
simple:
retry:
enabled: true
initial-interval: 3s
max-attempts: 6
max-interval: 10s
multiplier: 2

i hope it gonna help you [https://www.javainuse.com/messaging/rabbitmq/error]