# Using RequestHandlerRetryAdvice as per-class advice

Tags: spring-integration, spring-retry

In the [Spring Core Advice API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api-advice) there are two kinds of advice defined:

- per-class advice - which must not "depend on the state of the proxied object or add new state"
- per-instance advice - that "adds state to the proxied object"

[RequestHandlerRetryAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/handler/advice/RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.html), per javadocs, has a stateless and a stateful mode of operation.

Under which conditions can RequestHandlerRetryAdvice be used as per-class advice?  (ie use a single bean to advise several handlers).

Can a "stateless mode" instace be used as per-class advice ?

Can a "stateful mode" instance be used as per-class advice ?

I could not find information on whether RequestHandlerRetryAdvice adds state to the proxied object, that are the required conditions to apply the criteria criteria of per-class/per-object advices, as documented in the Spring Core reference.

My expectation is that in stateful mode, the advice cannot be used as per-class.

While for stateless mode it is unclear whether it extends the state. ( If shared by multiple handlers - it would require that at most one of them is using the retry advice at any given moment ? )

Note that [an answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393517/spring-integration-retry-do-i-need-a-separate-retry-bean-for-each-service-act) implies that it always can, because it is "thread safe". However, this condition is not sufficient to allow per-class usage, according to the Spring Core reference docs (referenced above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using stateful retry in this environment, the state is (typically) maintained per message, not per handler; the same advice can be used on multiple handlers, as long as you don't expect messages that would generate the same identifier to hit multiple handlers concurrently on different threads (which would be very unusual). But even that case can be accommodated with an appropriate state generator.

From the [Spring Integration Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#retry-advice)...

> To make retry stateful, we need to provide the Advice with a `RetryStateGenerator` implementation. This class is used to identify a message as being a resubmission so that the RetryTemplate can determine the current state of retry for this message. The framework provides a `SpelExpressionRetryStateGenerator` which determines the message identifier using a SpEL expression.

Comment: And for stateless retry - this is always safe, right ?
( I just want to make sure - I could not determine from reading the code alone that none of the object hierarchy under the advice keeps any state. )

Comment: Correct; there is no state to maintain. The circuit breaker advice is also safe - it maintains state for each target.